# Why lambda returns bool?

Tags: c++, qt, c++11, return, return-type

I've started learning C++11 and C++14 and i have a question. Why lambda not returns 23?

```
template<class T>
auto func(T t)
{
    return t;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    auto abc = []()->auto { return func(23); };
    qDebug() << abc; // output: true

    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: I've retagged, adding "Qt" so an expert might be able to answer detailing the implicit conversion to bool when outputting the lambda type.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to actually *execute* the lambda:

```
qDebug() << abc();
```

Currently the `<<` overload is converting the *type* of the lambda to a `bool`, and outputting that.

Comment: @МишаковМаксим: The implicit conversion to `bool` is interesting though: I don't use Qt so can't explain more; might be interesting if you stepped through the library code.

Comment: Question on the side, as I've had this issue (something being "captured" by the `bool` overload to `operator<<`) with pointers before: Is the type of the lambda `abc`, at this point, *technically* a pointer of some description, or is it (in the legalese of C++) something else entirely?

Comment: @DevSolar: Methinks that's a question in itself - I'm not equipped to answer that one thoroughly, although a lambda has a compiler-generated type. Good job we have `auto`!

Answer (score 19):

As @Bathsheba pointed out. You have a typo and don't call the lambda. Now, it's rather obvious that `operator<<` for `qDebug()` is not overloaded on the lambda's closure type. So naturally an implicit conversion sequence has to happen. The only available one, *and only because your lambda is capture-less*, starts with a conversion to a function pointer.

Now, [which overload of `operator<<`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdebug.html) can be used to print a function pointer? On the face of it, two likely candidates:

```
operator<<(bool t)         // Because it prints true, duh
operator<<(const void *p)  // Because pointers :)
```

So why the `bool` overload? Because a function pointer is not implicitly convertible to `void*`. That conversion is conditionally supported, and must be performed with a cast ([[expr.reinterpret.cast]/8](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/expr.reinterpret.cast#8)):

> Converting a function pointer to an object pointer type or vice versa
>   is conditionally-supported.

That leaves us only with [[conv.bool]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/conv.bool):

> A prvalue of arithmetic, unscoped enumeration, pointer, or pointer to
>   member type can be converted to a prvalue of type bool.

Comment: ...and that saved me the posting of the question I'd asked Bathsheba. Thank you for clarifying. ;-)

Comment: "only because your lambda is capture-less" -- meaning that a capturing lambda *cannot* convert to a function pointer, but is a distinct, non-pointer type?

Comment: @DevSolar: You best ask that question after all? Then StoryTeller will hit the rep cap by lunchtime GMT.

Comment: @DevSolar - A lambda expression always introduces a distinct type. But yeah, a capturing lambda doesn't support any conversions. The only obvious one is not available because there's state to consider.

Comment: @Bathsheba - It just happened. And SO rewarded me with a literal Rep Cap for the winter bash. How does it look?

Comment: @StoryTeller: Fantastic. I love the way you can position the hat this year.

Comment: relevant: [`[expr.prim.lambda.closure]/7`](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim.lambda#closure-7).